# aggregate sort limit with lodash/underscore

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, underscore.js, lodash

i need to aggregate my data. this would be easy if i use mongodb aggregation,, but i want to perform in client side. LoDash  or Underscore should solve this...

suppose i have this data:

```
var data = [
    {
        "uId" : "u1",
        "qId" : "q1",
        "share" : 2,
        "star"  :   2,
        "score" : 5
    },
    {
        "uId" : "u1",
        "qId" : "q2",
        "share" : 2,
        "star"  :   2,
        "score" : 5
    }.
    {
        "uId" : "u2",
        "qId" : "q1",
        "share" : 2,
        "star"  :   2,
        "score" : 5
    },
    {
        "uId" : "u2",
        "qId" : "q2",
        "share" : 3,
        "star"  :   3,
        "score" : 7
    },
    {
        "uId" : "u3",
        "qId" : "q1",
        "share" : 3,
        "star"  :   3,
        "score" : 7
    },
    {
        "uId" : "u3",
        "qId" : "q2",
        "share" : 3,
        "star"  :   3,
        "score" : 7
    }
]
```

i need this result:

```
result = [
    {
        "uId" : "u3",
        "qId" : 2,
        "share" : 6,
        "star"  :   6,
        "score" : 14
    },
    {
        "uId" : "u2",
        "qId" : 2,
        "share" : 5,
        "star"  :   5,
        "score" : 12
    }
]
```

it sort by highest score and limit the result to only show 2 results

thank You...

Comment: If you are querying a collection to return this data why do you think handling this client side is better than using [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)?

Comment: @user3100115 i don't know, maybe i should edit my question then...

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this in underscore.

```
_.sortBy(data, 'score').reverse().splice(0, 2);
```

not sure how performant the reverse would be though.

EDIT:

got it without the reverse:

```
_.sortBy(data, function (el) { return -el.score; }).splice(0, 2);
```

Comment: you could use `.limit(2)` instead of  `.slice(0, 2)`

Comment: appearantly not @hitman4890 this is plain javascript arrays they do not have a `.limit()` on their prototype [see mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) for a list of array methods.

Comment: ok. my bad. Although I think it can be used if we use `.chain()`. `In addition, the Array prototype's methods are proxied through the chained Underscore object, so you can slip a reverse or a push into your chain, and continue to modify the array.`

Comment: @hitman4890 that would make since with the chain. I still don't see a limit in the underscore library though. Possibly you mean initial?

Comment: @John thats much better

Comment: hi @John thank You for your answer,,however it only sorting and limiting,, aggregating not work...

Comment: I was confused by the question how you would aggregate only a single source of data. I"m assuming now that there are multiple datasets, could you specify how your data sets are being sent to your javascript?

Comment: By the way I could take a guess at what you would need to aggregate and I would probably use the array's (.concat() method)[ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat] you could use it like `data = data.concat(data2, data3)` before you call the sort and limit function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash for it :

```
_.map(_.sortByOrder(data, ['score'], ['desc']), _.values).slice(0,2);
```

First it will create a sorted array and then limit the result to have only two results.

Comment: but, aggregation is not happening?\

Comment: It stands for descending order or highest to lowest.

Comment: @KarinaL it sort the records in  descending order